# Enabling ssh in solr jetty 9

Tags: ssh, solr, jetty-9

Trying to enable ssh in solr of jetty version 9. But getting "Password mismatch error"

```
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:867)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:256)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about *SSL* and not *SSH*.

The error message tells you that Java is unable to decrypt the private keys, which it does with the password provided to the application container.

If you check out "[Enabling SSL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL#EnablingSSL-Generateaself-signedcertificateandakey)" in the manual, there's a section that gives examples for how to set the passwords as environment variables when starting Solr (in solr.in.sh - refer to the section in the manual):

```
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
```

These passwords are used to decrypt the private keys for the container, and if wrong or missing will end up with a password verification error.

Comment: Follwed the link you have shared. but still getting this error "Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have."